# Cookbook Yum Not Found on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, yum, chef-solo

I am using little chef github.com/tobami/littlechef to install graphite on an ubuntu 14.04 vm using virtualbox and vagrant.

The node that describes the ubuntu server looks like this

```
{
    "chef_environment": "_default",
    "name": "local_monitoring",
    "platform": "debian",
    "run_list": [
        "recipe[graphite]"
    ]
}
```

When I attempt to run the following command ...

```
fix node:local_monitoring
```

... I get the following error message.

```
    == Configuring local_monitoring ==
Synchronizing nodes, environments, roles, cookbooks and data bags...

Cooking...
[2014-12-31T01:40:58+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-12-31T01:40:58+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.8 ***
[2014-12-31T01:40:58+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 19967
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[graphite]"] from CLI options
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[graphite]]
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [graphite]
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for local-monitoring
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef-solo/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook yum not found. If you're loading yum from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
[2014-12-31T01:41:04+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

FAILED: chef-solo could not finish configuring the node

Disconnecting from vagrant@127.0.0.1:2001... done.
```

I have the graphite cookbook found here github.com/hw-cookbooks/graphite installed in my coobooks directory.

I read about a similar problem here lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2013-02/msg00409.html , so I downloaded the yum cookbook from here https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum and added it to my run list, but when I run `fix node:local_monitoring`, I get the following output.

```
== Configuring local_monitoring ==
Synchronizing nodes, environments, roles, cookbooks and data bags...

Cooking...
[2014-12-31T01:47:18+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-12-31T01:47:18+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.8 ***
[2014-12-31T01:47:18+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 20308
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[yum]", "recipe[graphite]"] from CLI options
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[yum], recipe[graphite]]
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [yum, graphite]
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for local-monitoring
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef-solo/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook yum not found. If you're loading yum from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
[2014-12-31T01:47:24+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

FAILED: chef-solo could not finish configuring the node

Disconnecting from vagrant@127.0.0.1:2001... done.
```

I really don't know what to do here, or what could be causing the problem. Any help would be appreciated . If I need to clarify something let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: that cookbook needs to be updated to support ubuntu, IE use `package` to do the installation.  This will make it use `apt-get install` rather than `yum`

Comment: The above comment is incorrect and not related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [graphite cookbook depends on `yum`](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/graphite/blob/master/metadata.rb#L18-L22). Because Chef cookbook dependencies have to be purely static, they cannot be per-platform so you need this even on platforms that it won't actually be used with. This is why tools like Berkshelf are popular to manage downloads and dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Why would Chef still not be able to find the yum cookbook even after I included it in my runlist?

Comment: Did you actually download and unpack the yum cookbook in to your cookbooks folder (along with all the other dependencies)?

Comment: I cloned the repositories from here https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum and here https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum-epel. I put it in my cookbooks directory.